# Java Case Switcher

Tags: java, string, char, return, case-sensitive

So I'm writing a little return program that switches the case of characters in a string, so HELLo becomes hElLo and hello becomes HeLlO, and aaa becomes AaA. I'm having a bit of trouble though. I'm still new and learning java, so sorry if this breaks rules:

```
public static String altCase(String text){
      String str = "";
      for (int i = 0; i <= text.length()-1; i++)
      {
        char ch = text.charAt(i);
        boolean lastIsUpperCase = true;
        if(Character.isUpperCase(i-1))
        {
          lastIsUpperCase = true;
        }
        else if(Character.isLowerCase(i-1))
        {
          lastIsUpperCase = false;
        }

        if(lastIsUpperCase)
        {
          str += Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        }   
        else if (!lastIsUpperCase)
        {
          str += Character.toUpperCase(ch);
        }
      }
      return str;
 }
```

Comment: `Character.isUpperCase(i-1)` is your problem and `Character.isLowerCase(i-1)` Should be maybe... `Character.isUpperCase(ch)` and `Character.isLowerCase(ch)`

Comment: You have to explain what the problem is. Then, if there are any errors, add the error message. If there is a stack trace, add the stack trace. Also mark where in the code the error happens by adding a comment. Edit your question and add all of this information to the question. Remember to format!

Comment: Just an FYI, but your code snippet does not contain ANY switch-cases. This would be more practical than using a nested if-statement...

Comment: Start the loop at `i=1`, not `i=0`.

Comment: @ryekayo OP is trying to switch (change) the case (letter case, upper or lower) of characters, not to use `switch` and `case`.

Comment: I understand, but a switch-case can still be used in this instance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to do it.

```
public static String altCase(String text){
      String str = "";
      str += Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(0));
      for (int i = 1; i <= text.length()-1; i++)
      {
        char ch = text.charAt(i);
        boolean lastUp = flipFlop(i);
        char temp = switcher(ch, lastUp);
        str+=temp;
      }
      return str;
 }
 public static boolean flipFlop (int i){
      boolean bool = true;
      if(i==1){
        bool = true;
      }
      else if((i%2)==0)
      {
           bool = false;
      }
      else if((i%2)!=0)
      {
           bool = true;
      }
      return bool;
 }
 public static char switcher (char ch, boolean lastUp){
   char temp = ch;
   if(lastUp){
        temp = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
   }
   else if (lastUp==false){
     temp = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
   }
   return temp;
 }
```

I added a 'flipFlop' method to track the iterations, and the method 'switcher' changes between upper and lower case based on the condition of the last char. (lastUp is true when the last character in the string is uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

You should add the char to your if clause as in:

```
      String str = "";
      for (int i = 0; i <= text.length()-1; i++)
      {
        char ch = text.charAt(i);

        if(Character.isUpperCase(ch))
        {
          str += Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        }
        else if(Character.isLowerCase(ch))
        {
            str += Character.toUpperCase(ch);
        }


      }
      return str;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build up the return value, and you could also use a [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) and a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Finally, you can test if a character is lower case (or upper case) and then swap the case. Something like,

```
public static String altCase(String text) {
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
        return text;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.length());
    for (char ch : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
        } else if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
        } else {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: **I'm still new and learning java, so sorry if this breaks rules** if he is new to java he would most likely not understand what the `StringBuilder` class does, nor would he understand the for-each loop of `for (char ch : text.toCharArray())`. It's always better to write non-complex code you understand than to use code you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a char array and then check and swap each element individually. When you are done just pass that char array to a string as argument to make it into a string

```
char[] word = new char[3];
String str = new String(word);
```