# Trying to change a string to altcase

Tags: java, for-loop, char

Trying to write a code that makes a string become altcase (ie. "hello" becomes "HeLlO". I borrowed code from another question on this forum that asked for something similar ([Java Case Switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029652/java-case-switcher)) However, the code only switched the casing of a letter instead of having a capital letter (first), then lowercase letter, etc. pattern.

What I have so far:

```
public String altCase(String text)
{
      String str = "";
      for (int i = 0; i <= text.length(); i++)
       {
        char cA = text.charAt(i);

        if (text.charAt(0).isUppercase)
        {
            str += Character.toLowerCase(cA);
        }

        if (text.charAt(0).isLowercase)
        {
            str += Character.toUpperCase;
        }

        if(i != 0 && Character.isUpperCase(cA))
        {
          if (text.charAt(i)-1.isUpperCase || text.charAt(i)+1.isUpperCase)
          {
              str += Character.toLowerCase(cA);
          }

          else
          {
              str += cA;
          }
        }

    if(i != 0 && Character.isLowerCase(cA))
        {
            if (text.charAt(i)-1.isLowerCase || text.charAt(i)+1.isLowerCase)
            {
            str += Character.toUpperCase(cA);
            }

            else
            {
                str += cA;
            }
        }
   }
      return str;
 }
```

I'm still relatively new to coding in general so please excuse my inefficiencies, as well as any headaches I might induce from the lack of experience in my coding. I cannot tell where I am going wrong except maybe when I typed "text.charAt(i)-1.isLowerCase" as the statement seems a bit illogical, but I am lost in terms of trying to come up with something else that would accomplish the same thing. Or is my error completely elsewhere? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Look carefully at your parentheses.

Comment: Did I miss a parentheses, add one, or misuse them? Can't seem to find the first two.

Comment: What do you think `text.charAt(i)-1` means? What are you subtracting from?

Answer (score 1):

If I truly understand what you want to get is that:

Get a string, change it in a format of AbCdEfG.... and so on.

There is more simple solution.
Get a string and with for loop, for every character, change character size depending on position in string, for i%2 == 0 upper case, and i%2 == 1 lower case.

```
public String altCase(String text)
{
   String str = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
   {
        char cA = text.charAt(i);

        if (i%2 == 0)
        {
            str += Character.toUpperCase(cA);
        }
        else
        {
           str += Character.toLowerCase(cA);
        }
  }  
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [modulus operator](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-mod.html) could take you a long way here...

```
StringBuilder rslt = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    switch (i % 2) {
        case 0:
            rslt.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
            break;
        case 1:
            rslt.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
            break;
    }
}
return rslt.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (a *mutable* character sequence) of `text.toLowerCase()`; then set the characters at even indices to their capital equivalents (and your method doesn't appear to depend on instance state, so it might be `static`). Something like,

```
public static String altCase(String text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.toLowerCase());
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i += 2) {
        sb.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(i)));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IntStream.range(0, s.length()).mapToObj(i -> i % 2 == 0 ?
      Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)) : 
      Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)))
      .map(String::valueOf)
      .collect(Collectors.joining());
```